# Custom MySql Query

Tags: mysql

sorry for the title, i can't find a short name or description for my problem.

Table_A : each row is a user request (id,...,status)

Table_B : each request in Table_A can have 1 or more rows in Table_B as sub sections for the request (id,request_id,....,status)

My system process the rows in Table_B with cron, with multiple crons running simultaneously. The cron sets the status in Table_B to 3(done) when its finished.

Now i need to know when all the subsections(Table_B row) for each request(Table_A) is finished so i can update the status in Table_A.

What i am doing now is selecting the first request in Table_A (TOP 1) then get the status for all the subsections in Table_B and check if all of them have status==3, this works but i wanted to be able to this with single query, without the need to check the values in the code.

Something like this :

```
select the request_id's 
  from Table_B where **all the rows** with this request_id has status=3
```

Any idea? any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT request_id
FROM Table_B
GROUP BY request_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN status <> 3 THEN 1 END) = 0
```

This will select the `request_id` values that are **only** related to `status = 3`.

**Note:** I assume that `status` is a `NOT NULL` field.

Comment: tnx this seems to be working, how much impact using a query like this will have on performance? considering a table with 100,000+ rows

Comment: It should perform OK if the table is properly indexed. You can try it with your actual data and tell us how it performs. Alternatively you can try `NOT EXISTS` and see how it compares.

Comment: `having` seems to be much faster in my small test table, it took `0.0005 sec` where `NOT EXIST` query written below by @DRapp with subquery on the same table took `0.0476 sec`. but i think i should do another test with a larger table to be sure.

Comment: @Exlord Very well, continue with your tests and get back to us when you have tested against a larger dataset.

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
select
      a.id
   from
      Table_A a
   where 
      a.id NOT EXISTS( select b.request_id
                          from Table_B b
                          where a.id = b.request_id
                            AND b.staus <> 3 )
```

if Table_B is indexed on (request_id, status).  The NOT EXISTS, runs until it finds ANY that match the query instead of EVERY RECORD that matches in the subquery, so it should quickly jump between 1 record to the next.

Comment: tnx , this works but it seems `having` is much faster.